# Single AJAX call for multiple Datatables

Tags: jquery, datatables

I'm trying to use this to get data for about 8 tables I have on a long page. I'm testing it on one table with the below code to see if I can get it to work, but so far no go.

It gets the data just fine if I console.log. However, when I try to render the table, I get this error:

Requested unknown parameter '1' for row 0. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/4

```
$.ajax({
url: 'all_data.php',
type: 'GET',
success: function(data) {
$("#recode_num").DataTable({
      data:data,
      "columns": [
            { "title": "cat_code" },
            { "title": "value" },
            { "title": "database_percent" },
            { "title": "national_percent" },
            { "title": "index_value" }
          ],

      });
  }
});
```

However, if I do this, it works fine, so I know I have the right number of columns, cells, etc.

```
 $("#recode_num").DataTable({
     "ajax": {
      "url":"all_data.php",
      "type":"GET"
      } ,
      "columns": [
            { "title": "cat_code" },
            { "title": "value" },
            { "title": "database_percent" },
            { "title": "national_percent" },
            { "title": "index_value" }
          ],

      });
```

What else could be causing this problem?

Comment: instead of data: data did you tried "data": data  ? since you have a var named data these can couse a misunderstading. idk if this is the problemm if that doesnt solve the problem put a fiddle so we can help you better

Comment: @kabstergo, there is no difference between `data : data` and `"data": data` in a javascript object.

Comment: can u make a fiddle so we can help you better?